# How to update SQL field using function and stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, stored-procedures, sql-update

What I want to do is to update column (NewID) in my table (SampleTable) with the following code, but it's not working.. can somebody help me please? Whats wrong with it?

I have the table 'SampleTable' wich has the fields 'NewID' and 'OldID'.

```
UPDATE SampleTable SET NewID = dbo.fn_DoStuff(OldID) <-- Not working
```

My function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_DoStuff]
( 
   @int oldid
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @returnValue int
    EXEC @returnValue = dbo.spc_DoStuff @oldid  
    RETURN @returnValue
END
```

My stored procedure:

SampleTable1 has the columns ID, SomeColName.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spc_GeraAtriðisorðalistaÚrAtriðisorði]
(
    @oldid int
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @returnValue int
    INSERT INTO SampleTable1 (SomeColName) VALUES (null)
    SET @returnValue = @@IDENTITY
    INSERT INTO SampleTable2 (SomeColName1, SomeColName2) VALUES (@returnValue, @oldid)
    SELECT @returnValue AS RetVal
END
```

Comment: what error do you see?

Comment: The term "not working" is too vague.  What does it mean?

Comment: You may consider adding a `where` clause

Comment: Is it working if you comment out the 2 insert statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your solution GarethD I could still not call the function like I wanted to

```
UPDATE SampleTable SET NewID = dbo.fn_DoStuff(OldID).
```

Your code helped me though to start thinking another way. Now I'm using a cursor and a while loop and it works perfectly. See my solution below:

```
DECLARE @OldID AS INT

DECLARE Upd_CURSOR FOR
SELECT OldID
FROM dbo.SampleTable
WHERE  OldID is not null
FOR UPDATE OF NewID

OPEN Upd_CURSOR;
FETCH NEXT FROM Upd_CURSOR INTO @OldID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN          
      DECLARE @returnValue int;
      INSERT INTO SampleTable1 (SomeColName) VALUES (null);
      SET @returnValue = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
      INSERT INTO SampleTable2 (SomeColName1, SomeColName2) VALUES (@returnValue, @OldID)
      UPDATE dbo.SampleTable SET NewID = @returnValue WHERE CURRENT OF Upd_CURSOR;
      FETCH NEXT FROM Upd_CURSOR INTO @OldID;
   END;
CLOSE Upd_CURSOR;
DEALLOCATE Upd_CURSOR;
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 problems, the first is you cannot call a stored procedure inside a function, nor can you perform your insert within a function.

The second problem is that even if you could call a stored procedure inside a function, you are not returning the value from the procedure correctly. You would need something like:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T (ID INT IDENTITY, Filler CHAR(10));
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Test
AS 
    DECLARE @i INT;
    INSERT dbo.T (Filler) VALUES (NULL);
    RETURN  SCOPE_IDENTITY();
GO
```

*Note the use of the `RETURN` statement, if you don't use this the default return value is 0*

Then you can use:

```
DECLARE @i INT;
EXECUTE @i = dbo.Test;
SELECT ReturnVal = @i;
```

*Note, I have replaced @@IDENTITY with SCOPE_IDENTITY(), @@IDENTITY is rarely the correct function to use*

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/06c2e/1)**